# HTML content is not showing using woo filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to display youtube link after product images in single page using acf. It's showing link while I add by code but its not showing any html tag.here is my code.

[image: Code]

[image: Result which is not what I want]

Answer (score 0):

You're using `the_field`, which is a function that echoes the custom field. You want to be using `get_field()` instead when saving values in variables since it returns the field value.

Your line is equivalent to

```
$html .= '<a href="'. echo 'youtube.com/videoblabla'.'">Click here!</a>;
```

You should echo the `$html` value when using actions by the way. Filters need a returned value, action output stuff at a given place in the page so you should echo it instead.

Also you should use the wordpress stackexchange for WP and WooCommerce related questions.